# How to draw logic gates in conformity with official standards?

Tags: digital-logic

I know there is a standard that defines how to draw logic gates very precisely, based on precise rounds, angles, proportions etc. I heard about ANSI/IEEE Std 91a-1991, but I am not sure it really defines the rules ('algorithm') to draw the gates.

However, that is not so easy to find on the web. Maybe some of you know what I mean and can point to a document explaining how to achieve these drawings ?

Comment: The *A* in *ANSI* is for *American*. Is that not "us" enough?

Comment: IEEE Std91a-1991 is the standard. It is approved by the IEEE, ANSI, and has been made mandatory by the U.S. Department of Defense. Who are these "us" you speak of and what makes them think there should be another standard?

Comment: sorry for the "us" word that is misleading. In Europe we say "us" vs "IEC" symbols which in not correct, of course.

Answer (score 1):

The document you need is IEEE Std 91a-1991, "Standard Graphic Symbols for Logic Functions". The 1991 revision is supposed to conform to IEC 617-12 and includes IEC symbols. In particular, I think you want to look at Annex A, "Recommended Symbol Proportions".

Other standards that may be helpful are ANSI/IEEE Std 991, "Logic Circuit Diagrams", and IEEE Std 315-1975 (ANSI Y32.2-1975, CSA Z99-1975), "Graphic Symbols for Electrical and Electronics Diagrams".

These standards are available from the [IEEE](http://www.ieee.org/publications_standards/index.html).